# Why actor is(or represented) outside the system boundary of a system in use case?

Tags: uml, use-case

Why actor is (or represented) outside the system boundary of a  system in use case.

Is there any reason for this?
Explain with example.

Comment: Because according to the UML norm, it is the definition of an actor i.e. "Actors always model entities that are outside the system".

Comment: @RedBeard That's simply the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let me use a Business Actor and a Business Use Case as an analogy.

A Business Use Case represents a process of value to Business Actor.

So a Business Use Case for a Bank could be "Exchange Foreign Currency".

The Business Actor (Customer) interacts with the Business (Bank) to change the £s for $s ;-)

Is it not obvious that the Customer is not part of the Bank? An employee would be internal, but not a customer.

So change Business Actor to a (System) Actor. And let's assume we have an ATM (System) that can change currency. If you are writing a system use case, you are writing "requirements" for the ATM system. NOT the Customer Actor.

It is a user, NOT a system! All you can do is specify the interaction.

Now what happens with the Actor is a system? Like lets said, xe.com, which gives exchange rates?

The question you have to ask is, "Can I impose changes to xe.com, which is not part of the Bank system? Or do I just use the API?".

In the case of just using an API, then xe.com is an Actor. Changes to xe.com are outside the scope of YOUR project.

In the case of changing xe.com itself, then it is NOT an actor, it is part of your project/system.

That is the beauty of Actors! It helps you define the scope of your system you are allowed to change.

Hope this helps.